# sort folders by time php

Tags: php, subdirectory, dir

This code shows a list of folders.

How can I sort these folders by time (last changed) ?

```
function folderlist(){
  $startdir = './';
  $ignoredDirectory[] = '.'; 
  $ignoredDirectory[] = '..';
   if (is_dir($startdir)){
       if ($dh = opendir($startdir)){
           while (($folder = readdir($dh)) !== false){
               if (!(array_search($folder,$ignoredDirectory) > -1)){
                 if (filetype($startdir . $folder) == "dir"){
                       $directorylist[$startdir . $folder]['name'] = $folder;
                       $directorylist[$startdir . $folder]['path'] = $startdir;
                   }
               }
           }
           closedir($dh);
       }
   }
return($directorylist);
}

$folders = folderlist();
    foreach ($folders as $folder){
    $path = $folder['path'];
    $name = $folder['name'];

echo '<li><a href="' .$path .'index.php?imgdir=' .$name . '" class="style1"><font face="Tahoma" class="ws8"><B>' . $name . '</B></a><br /></li>';
  }
?>
```

Comment: There should be a question here, but the poor grammar and lack of punctuation makes it hard to find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must include `filemtime()` in your `$directoryList[]` and then sort your array by the mtime.

```
function cmp_mtime_reverse($a, $b) {
    if ($a['mtime'] == $b['mtime'])
        return 0;

    if ($a['mtime'] > $b['mtime'])
        return -1;

    return 1;
}

function folderlist() {
    $startdir = './';
    $ignoredDirectory[] = '.'; 
    $ignoredDirectory[] = '..';
    if (is_dir($startdir)) {
        if ($dh = opendir($startdir)) {
            while (($folder = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
                if (!(array_search($folder,$ignoredDirectory) > -1)) {
                    if (filetype($startdir . $folder) == "dir") {
                        $mtime = filemtime($startdir . $folder);
                        $directorylist[$startdir . $folder]['name'] = $folder;
                        $directorylist[$startdir . $folder]['path'] = $startdir;
                        $directorylist[$startdir . $folder]['mtime'] = $mtime;
                        $directorylist[$startdir . $folder]['files'] = count_files($startdir . $folder);
                    }
                }
            }

            closedir($dh);
        }
    }

    uasort($directorylist, 'cmp_mtime_reverse');
    return $directorylist;
}
```

See [Sorting Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) and [filemtime](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.filemtime.php) for more information.

To count files inside a folder

```
function count_files($startdir) {
    $ignoredDirectory[] = '.'; 
    $ignoredDirectory[] = '..';
    $n = 0;
    if ($dh = opendir($startdir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            if (!(array_search($file, $ignoredDirectory) > -1)) {
                $n++;
            }
        }

        closedir($dh);
    }

    return $n++;
}
```

and then add an entry in your function `folderlist()`

```
$directorylist[$startdir . $folder]['files'] = count_files($startdir . $folder);
```

Comment: @user1835767 I added your complete example.

Comment: olaf i want a count files inside the folder how can i edit in this code example folderx (23 files) folderz(2 files)

Comment: @user1835767 See my updated post. I also modified `folderList()`, because in the previous version two folders with the same mtime would be shown as one.

Comment: your 1st code is perfect i think becz in this code lastest folder show on last

Comment: @user1835767 I fixed the sort order and added the additional line to `folderList()`

Comment: i change my code page show errorFatal error: Call to undefined function count_files() in /home/sam/public_html/albums//dirs.php on line 26

Comment: i think in echo line countfile value is not there thats why this error coming

Comment: @user1835767 Have you included the function `count_files()` in your PHP source?

Comment: yes i include it already but now directory is fine but file count is not working which value i put it on echo line? i put it <B>' . $count_files . '</B> but no value return

Comment: @user1835767 In your loop, you can insert `'<b>' . $folder['files'] . '</b>'`

Comment: @user1835767 You can also use `'<b>' . count_files('/path/to/folder') . '</b>'`

Comment: is it possible count only specific format  i want only .jpg file count

Comment: @user1835767 Of course, you can extend `count_files()` however you like. Insert a test in the loop and you can restrict the type of files. If you need help for that, please open a new question.

Comment: @user1835767 I'm sure, there are lots of experts willing to help. I'm now away for some time, but I will look into it later.